# Ruby On Rails - Can we use varchar column for saving serialized data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Need to store a serialized hash into mysql. Since the size of hash is going to be very small, i decided to use a varchar for saving the serialized data instead of text column. I am using **mysql** with **rails 3**.

Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :monday
end
```

When I do the following,

```
u = User.new
u.monday = {:from => "10:00", :to => "04:00"}
u.save
```

I get following error "TypeError: class or module required". Shouldn't we use varchar for serialized data?

Comment: Not sure if you can store a range (two times) in a single date or time column.  Where are te 'from' and 'to' defined.  most problrm in rails are from non-standard usage.  btw don't choose a data type based on a hash being "very small".  choose good solutions that are easy to maintain and read over trying to pack info into less bytes.  Thankfully that is needed less these days gicen power and storage

Answer (score 2):

You need a :text database datatype to use the serialize option.